# how to make the GameObject have a parameter in unity (c#)?

Tags: c#, variables, unity-game-engine, gameobject

please help me how to get the value of "currentPeople.timeCount;"
for example i have a script:

```
public class BuildingPlacement : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject currentPeople;public int DelayTime;private int timeCount;
}
```

if i want to say that

```
DelayTime = currentPeople.timeCount;
```

i try this code below and it says nullreferenceexception object reference not set to an instance of an object:

```
DelayTime = (BuildingPlacement)currentPeople.GetComponent(typeof(BuildingPlacement).timeCount);
```

How do I get the value of `currentPeople.timeCount` ? is it possible?

Comment: Post your question and code here. Do not upload question as an image

Comment: thanks for the correction, first using stackoverflow haha

Comment: is it like that? i mean at first the GameObject currentPeople doesnt have currentPeople.timeCount , but i want to get the value of currentPeople.timeCount,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add a variable to a GameObject as mentioned in your [original](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41339231/3) question. It is very likely you want to add the script to the GameObject which also makes the `timeCount` variable available to that GameObject.

If that's the case then select the `currentPeople` GameObject and drag the `BuildingPlacement` script to it in the Editor. This is called attaching script to a GameObject. You can also do this via code with:

```
currentPeople.AddComponent<BuildingPlacement>();
```

To access the `timeCount` variable that is in the `BuildingPlacement` script which is attached to the `currentPeople` GameObject:

```
 int value =  currentPeople.GetComponent<BuildingPlacement>().timeCount;
```

It seems like you are lacking the basic knowledge of Unity. You can start from [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials).

Comment: Also, `timeCount` variable should be made public so, `private int timeCount` should be `public  int timeCount`

Comment: Thankyou for your help it works, yeah im starting using unity serveral weeks ago haha